# elementFromPoint not recognising certain elements

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with which I've been battling for a couple of days now and I cannot understand what the problem is.

I want to fire up an event when a certain element hits the top of my `<div>`. It works well with most of the elements in my document except one, which incidentally is the one I'm interested in.

They're all `span`, with different classes. I'm detecting the class with `el.classList.contains("myclass")`. See my snippet below, with `pagenum` in the function, which gets picked up (although several times, but that's another minor issue). It works with `line`, `line-group`, and `pagenum`. It doesn't work with `mspage`.

Can someone tell me please what I am missing?

Thanks.

### Update

I just noticed that if I give the `mspage` elements a height of 2 rem then it does detect them. Ideally I wanted those `span`s to be invisible to the user, and if I use `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` they don't get caught.

```js
document.getElementById('xslt-transformation').addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {

    const el = document.elementFromPoint(this.getBoundingClientRect().x, this.getBoundingClientRect().y);
    if (el.classList.contains("pagenum")) {


            console.log(el.id)

        
    }
});
```

```css
html, body, #mapdiv{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#xslt-transformation {

max-height: 63vh;
overflow: auto;

}

.mspage {
  display: block;
}

.line {
  display: block;
}

.line-group {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.footnotes {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
}

.catchword {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem
}

.diva-wrapper {
    min-height: 70vh !important;
  }
```

```html
<div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="transcription" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="transcription-tab">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Transcription</h5>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Your beautiful transcription here</h6>

                                    <div id="xslt-transformation">
                                        

                                    
         
            
<span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 003"></span>    
        
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line"><del>Latha gan raibh Padric 'na * Mhùr</del></span>
               <span class="line"><del>Cha raibh sailm air ùidh, ach ceol.</del></span>
               <span class="line"><del>Chaidh è thigh Oissain Mhic Fhinn,</del></span>
               <span class="line"><del>O sann leis bu bhinn a ghloir.</del></span>
            </span>
         
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Failt ort fein, a shean-fhir shuairc,</span>
               <span class="line">Air chuairt thugad thainig mi,</span>
               <span class="line">A laoich mhòir <span>***</span> mhìlidh nach meat</span>
               <span class="line">Cha d' eur thu riamh neach mu d'ni.</span>

            </span>
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Sgeul a b'ait leom fhaotainn uait</span>
               <span class="line">Odha Chuthaill is cruaidh colg,</span>
               <span class="line">An Cath is tinn' a thug an Fhiann</span>
               <span class="line">O na ghineadh tu riamh 'n an lorg</span>
            </span>

            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Dh'innsinn sin duitse gun dàil,</span>
               <span class="line">Dheagh Mhic Ailpein nan salm binn,</span>
               <span class="line">An Cath is tinn' a thug na fir</span>
               <span class="line">O'n a ghin iad Fiannaibh Fhinn.</span>
            </span>

            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Dearmad air † fleadh a rinn Fionn</span>
               <span class="line">Ann  Albuinn ri h àm nan laoch, </span>  
               
       
               <span class="footnotes">Footnotes: * Lùth-chuirt †cuirm, fèisd</span>
               <span class="catchword">Chuir</span>
               
               <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 004"></span>
               
               <span class="pagenum" id="p4">4</span>
               
               <span class="line">Chuir pairt do'n Fheinn fui' struim dearg,</span>
               <span class="line">Dh'eirich orra fearg is fraoch</span>
            </span>
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Tre Chaoilte Mhic Rannachair mhoir</span>
               <span class="line">'S Mac o Dòrain a bhi leinn,</span>
               <span class="line">Mar sud is Àillidh maith ùr</span>
               <span class="line">Thug breiteachd bliadhna ri Mùr Fhinn</span>
            </span>
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Ghluais an trithear a dh'Fhiannaibh Fhinn</span>
               <span class="line">Gu Righ Lochlann nan srian sliom,</span>
               <span class="line">Seirbheis blia'na thug iad dha</span>
               <span class="line">'N trithear a bha 'n ùidh ri h uaill.</span>
            </span>
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Gabh Bann-righ Lochlann nan sgiath donn</span>
               <span class="line">Trom ghaoil trom, 's cha∧<del>'s cha</del> b' ann gu deas,</span>
               <span class="line">Air Àillidh greadhnach nan arm geur</span>
               <span class="line">Gus an d'èirich a cheilg leis.</span>
            </span>
            
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Ghluais i a leabuidh an Righ</span>
               <span class="line">An gniomh mun do dhoirteadh an fhuil,</span>
               <span class="line">Gu hAlbuinn fhlathail nam Fiann</span>
               <span class="line">Thugadar an triath th'air muir.</span>
            </span>
            
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Bha Righ air Lochlann san uair</span>
               <span class="line">Leis am buinnte buaidh is blàr</span>
               <span class="line">Earragan Mac Ainnir nan lonng,</span>
               <span class="line">A Righ bu mhaith a làmh 's a lann.</span>
            </span> 
            

            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Chruinnich Righ Lochlann mor shluagh</span>
               <span class="line">Cabhlach cruaidh a dh'fhàs gu treun:</span>
               
               <span class="catchword">Dh'èirich</span>
  
             
               <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 005"></span>
               
               <span class="pagenum" id="p5">5</span>
               
               <span class="line">Dh'èirich sud o'n àirde tuath</span>
               <span class="line">Naoi Righrin, 's an sluagh leis.</span>
            </span> 
            
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Sheol iad air an abhais àrd</span>
               <span class="line">O chòrs Eirinn bu gharg gàir </span>
               <span class="line">Gu h Albuinn fhlathail nam Fiann </span>
               <span class="line">Thogadar an triath th' air muir.</span>
            </span> 
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Teachdoireachd thainig∧ thugainn gu luath,</span>
               <span class="line">Sgeula cruaidh chuir ruinn gu geur,</span>
               <span class="line">Còmhrag nam fear Innse-fàil </span>
               <span class="line">Fhaolainn air an tràigh mu dheas.</span>
            </span> 
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Thairig Fionn doibh cumha mhòr</span>
               <span class="line">Làn an tunna do'n dearg òr:</span>
               <span class="line">Do Righ Lochlann nan arm sean,</span>
               <span class="line">Araon, agus a bhean fein.</span>
            </span> 
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Lochlannaich a bhuithinn bhorb</span>
               <span class="line">Le meud an stoirm as an lèathachd</span>
               <span class="line">Cha ghabh iad cumha fui'm ghrein</span>
               <span class="line">Gun an Fheinn a bhi 'n an dèigh</span>
            </span> 
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Comhairl' eil' a chinn aig Fionn,</span>
               <span class="line">'S aig maithibh na Feinne gu leir;</span>
               <span class="line">Nighean Righ na' n gabht' i uath,</span>
               <span class="line">Gun d'fhuair è sud, 's a bhean fhein.</span>
            </span> 
            
            <span class="catchword">Chuir</span>
            
            <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 006"></span>
            
            <span class="pagenum" id="p6">6</span>
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Chuir sinn 'ga fhios nighean Righ</span>
               <span class="line">Bu ghuirme sùil, 's bu ghrinne meur;</span>
               <span class="line">Chuir sinne ga coimhead ceud each</span>
               <span class="line">A b'fhearr ris an deachaidh srian,</span>
               <span class="line">Le'n ceud marcaich air a' muin</span>
               <span class="line">Fui' chulaibh shròil le'n laste gniomh</span>
            </span> 
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Theirinn i'n sud air n raon,</span>
               <span class="line">'S dh'fhàg i 'na dèigh na h eich,</span>
               <span class="line">Thug i ceum uighe d' an coir</span>
               <span class="line">'S da choinnleir air 'na làimh dheis,</span>
               <span class="line">Da choinneil air ghuaillnibh a guin</span>
               <span class="line">'S dealbh a chrùin o gheug nam port</span>
            </span> 
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Do naigheachds' o phobull Fhinn</span>
               <span class="line">Innis dhuinn a bhri', 's a bheachd?</span>
               <span class="line">Mo naigheachds' o phobull Fhinn</span>
               <span class="line">Gum faigheadh tu bhri' gu ceart;</span>
            </span> 
            
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Mu rinn do bhean ort beairt chli,</span>
               <span class="line">'S gun d'iomair i 'n gniomh gu cearr:</span>
               <span class="line">Thoir cairdeas is comunn do dh'Fhionn</span>
               <span class="line">'S gum faigheadh tu mi 'na geall.</span>
            </span> 
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Gheibhe tu sud is ciad seud,</span>
               <span class="line">Is ciad leug o'n uirbhich shaor:</span>
               <span class="line">Gheibhe tu <del>sud</del>ceud seothag suairc'</span>
               <span class="line">Air am bitheadh buaidh nan eun:</span>
            </span> 
            <span class="catchword">Gheibhe</span>
   
            
            <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 007"></span> 
            
            <span class="pagenum" id="p7">7</span>
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Gheibhe tu sud is ciad mias</span>
               <span class="line">Do chùrsa Righ bheath' an àidh,</span>
               <span class="line">'S ge b' è ghleidheadh iad r' a bheo</span>
               <span class="line">Chumadh iad duin' òg a ghnà.</span>
            </span> 
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Gheibhe tu sud is ciad greidh,</span>
               <span class="line">Is làn Glinne do chridh bàn</span>
               <span class="line">'S a mhacain mar gabh thu sin </span>
               <span class="line">Thoir leat do bhean, 's thoir dhuinne sith.</span> 
            </span> 
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">'Ta cha d'thugainn sith do neach</span>
               <span class="line">Do dh' Àillidh, no ghin d' ar Feinn,</span>
               <span class="line">Ach Fionn fein a thigh 'n fui'm bhreith</span>
               <span class="line">Is a chreach a thoirt gu tràigh.</span>
            </span> 
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">'Ta cha d'thug thu leat do neart</span>
               <span class="line">Na bheireadh a chreach gu tràigh:</span>
               <span class="line">Falbhai mis' is beannachd leat,</span>
               <span class="line">O'n chaidh t aithneachd bun os cionn.</span>
            </span> 
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Cha'n fahlbh thus' a chiabh na'n cleachd,</span>
               <span class="line">A Ribhinn fharust a bheoil bhinn</span>
               <span class="line">Gheibhe tu na seuda saor,</span>
               <span class="line">'S cheanglainn thu ri m' thaobh deas.</span>
            </span> 
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Cha 'n fhan mis' a cheann na'n cliar,</span>
               <span class="line">O nach traogh mi t fhiamh, is t fhearg;</span>
               
               <span class="catchword">'S o</span>
          
               
               <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 008"></span> 
               
               <span class="pagenum" id="p8">8</span>
               
               <span class="line">'S nach faighinn saor fui' m' bhreith</span>
               <span class="line">Ceann na deise bu | ghann ciall </span>
            </span> 
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Cha 'n fhàg mi agaibh do theach</span>
               <span class="line">Do bheinn, no dh' amhuinn, no thulaich;</span>
               <span class="line">Ach Albuinn a thogail leom</span>
               <span class="line">'Na cròchcan glas ann am loinngeas.</span>
            </span> 
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Thionndaidh i ris a cùl,</span>
               <span class="line">'S mharcaich i do 'n chùirt gu dian:</span>
               <span class="line">Bu lion' ar sròl 'ga thogail suas,</span>
               <span class="line">'S ann òrdugh gu luath chaidh an Fhiann.</span>
            </span> 
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Fhreagair Àillidh 'n  còmhrag cruaidh, </span>
               <span class="line">Do 'n t sluagh a thainig ann gèill.</span>
               <span class="line">Ceann Mhic Nì', Mhic Naomh, Mhic Near,</span>
               <span class="line">Leigeadh leis air an treas beum.</span>
            </span> 
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Deich Ceannarda-fichead d'ar Feinn</span>
               <span class="line">'S ceann Àillidh fein air an tùs,</span>
               <span class="line">Thuit sud air laimh Earragainn mhoir</span>
               <span class="line">Man deachaidh na sloigh ann dlùths'.</span>
            </span> 
            
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">'N sin chaidh Fionn fein air thùs,</span>
               <span class="line">Deagh Mhac Chuthaill a ghnuis ghil;</span>
               <span class="line">'S deich Ceannard-fichead air a laimh dheis,</span>
               <span class="line">Do shiol Chuthaill na'n cleas lùth.</span>
            </span> 
            <span class="catchword">Labhair</span>
           
            <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 009"></span> 
            
            <span class="pagenum" id="p9">9</span>
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Labhair Fionn flath na'n cuach,</span>
               <span class="line">Ri maithibh uaislibh Innse-fàil;</span>
               <span class="line">Co dh'iongas Earragainn sa ghreis</span>
               <span class="line">Nan leigeamaid leis ar tàir.</span>
            </span> 
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">'S ann bha fhreagradh sud aig Goll</span>
               <span class="line">An Sonn a bha deachdair achlaoi.</span>
               <span class="line">D'iongaidh mi Earragainn sa ghreis</span>
               <span class="line">'S bheir mi d'fheuchainn d'a chleas lùithe.</span>
            </span> 
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Mac an Luthaich, 's Diarmad donn,</span>
               <span class="line">An t Oscar mòr, is Mac an Lèig,</span>
               <span class="line">Ga d' dhion o shrith-bhuillean an laoich,</span>
               <span class="line">Cum dithis air gach taobh do d' sgèith.</span>
            </span> 
                         

            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Dolphinne Mac Mhalcain o'n Ghrèig</span>
               <span class="line">* Muime Earragainn, 's cha bi bhreug,</span>
               <span class="line">'N àm sgathach a chinn d' a dhaltadh</span>
               <span class="line">A Ri' mhòir bu do amhluidh iomairt:</span>
               <span class="line">'S mar bhithe mi 's Fionn nam fleadh</span>
               <span class="line">Gum buineadh è 'n ceann do'n chearthar.</span>
            </span> 
            
<span class="footnotes">Footnotes: * Ge d' a tha ùghdar na h eachdrui so  
   a'g radh gum b'e Dolphinne Muime 
   Earragainn, tha 'n leughair r 'a thuig=,
   sinn gur è Oide bha ann. </span>

            <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 010"></span> 
            
            <span class="pagenum" id="p10">10</span>
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Seachd fichead 's mìle sonn</span>
               <span class="line">Thuit le Garadh, 's thuit le Goll:</span>
               <span class="line">Urdal le <del>Oissain an</del> Oscar an àidh,</span>
               <span class="line">'S le Conall, 's le Coireall cneas bhàn.</span>
            </span> 

            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">'S air a bhaiste thainig orm</span>
               <span class="line">A <del>Phadric</del>, chleirich a chanas na sailm,</span>
               <span class="line">Thuit leam fein, 's le Fionn nam fleadh</span>
               <span class="line">A cheart choi'-lion ceann ris a chearthar.</span>
            </span> 
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">'S mar duine chaidh as am beul airm,</span>
               <span class="line">No chaidh mar cheo do 'n ghrein;</span>
               <span class="line">Do dh'arm Righ Lochlann gu fior</span>
               <span class="line">Cha 'n fhac' iad riamh an tir fein.</span>
            </span>             
            
            <span class="line-group">
               <span class="line">Tuille mor is leith nam Fiann,</span>
               <span class="line">Thuit iad air an t sliabh mu dheas;</span>
               <span class="line">'S ge d' thainig cuid dhinne as </span>
               <span class="line">Cha d' rinn sinn an lath' ud ar leas.</span>
            </span>            
            
 

      </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `elementFromPoint` is not a good approach. Your interested element will not be detected if it doesn't happen to stay under that point. Even worse, the chances for a zero height element to be detected is zero. You should compare the `offsetTop` of your interested element with the `scrollTop + offsetTop` of the scrolling element. The `find` can be further optimised with binary search if necessary.

```js
let mspages = [...document.querySelectorAll(".mspage")];
let currentPage = mspages[0];
mspages = mspages.reverse();
document.getElementById('xslt-transformation').addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
    let mspage = mspages.find(p => e.target.scrollTop + e.target.offsetTop >= p.offsetTop );
    if (mspage != currentPage) {
        currentPage = mspage;
        console.log(currentPage?.id);
    }
});
```

```css
html, body, #mapdiv{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#xslt-transformation {

max-height: 63vh;
overflow: auto;

}

.mspage {
  display: block;
}

.line {
  display: block;
}

.line-group {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.footnotes {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
}

.catchword {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem
}

.diva-wrapper {
    min-height: 70vh !important;
  }
```

```html
<div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="transcription" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="transcription-tab">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Transcription</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Your beautiful transcription here</h6>

            <div id="xslt-transformation">





                <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 003"></span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line"><del>Latha gan raibh Padric 'na * Mhùr</del></span>
                    <span class="line"><del>Cha raibh sailm air ùidh, ach ceol.</del></span>
                    <span class="line"><del>Chaidh è thigh Oissain Mhic Fhinn,</del></span>
                    <span class="line"><del>O sann leis bu bhinn a ghloir.</del></span>
                </span>


                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Failt ort fein, a shean-fhir shuairc,</span>
                    <span class="line">Air chuairt thugad thainig mi,</span>
                    <span class="line">A laoich mhòir <span>***</span> mhìlidh nach meat</span>
                    <span class="line">Cha d' eur thu riamh neach mu d'ni.</span>

                </span>
                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Sgeul a b'ait leom fhaotainn uait</span>
                    <span class="line">Odha Chuthaill is cruaidh colg,</span>
                    <span class="line">An Cath is tinn' a thug an Fhiann</span>
                    <span class="line">O na ghineadh tu riamh 'n an lorg</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Dh'innsinn sin duitse gun dàil,</span>
                    <span class="line">Dheagh Mhic Ailpein nan salm binn,</span>
                    <span class="line">An Cath is tinn' a thug na fir</span>
                    <span class="line">O'n a ghin iad Fiannaibh Fhinn.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Dearmad air † fleadh a rinn Fionn</span>
                    <span class="line">Ann Albuinn ri h àm nan laoch, </span>


                    <span class="footnotes">Footnotes: * Lùth-chuirt †cuirm, fèisd</span>
                    <span class="catchword">Chuir</span>

                    <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 004"></span>

                    <span class="pagenum" id="p4">4</span>

                    <span class="line">Chuir pairt do'n Fheinn fui' struim dearg,</span>
                    <span class="line">Dh'eirich orra fearg is fraoch</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Tre Chaoilte Mhic Rannachair mhoir</span>
                    <span class="line">'S Mac o Dòrain a bhi leinn,</span>
                    <span class="line">Mar sud is Àillidh maith ùr</span>
                    <span class="line">Thug breiteachd bliadhna ri Mùr Fhinn</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Ghluais an trithear a dh'Fhiannaibh Fhinn</span>
                    <span class="line">Gu Righ Lochlann nan srian sliom,</span>
                    <span class="line">Seirbheis blia'na thug iad dha</span>
                    <span class="line">'N trithear a bha 'n ùidh ri h uaill.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Gabh Bann-righ Lochlann nan sgiath donn</span>
                    <span class="line">Trom ghaoil trom, 's cha∧<del>'s cha</del> b' ann gu deas,</span>
                    <span class="line">Air Àillidh greadhnach nan arm geur</span>
                    <span class="line">Gus an d'èirich a cheilg leis.</span>
                </span>


                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Ghluais i a leabuidh an Righ</span>
                    <span class="line">An gniomh mun do dhoirteadh an fhuil,</span>
                    <span class="line">Gu hAlbuinn fhlathail nam Fiann</span>
                    <span class="line">Thugadar an triath th'air muir.</span>
                </span>


                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Bha Righ air Lochlann san uair</span>
                    <span class="line">Leis am buinnte buaidh is blàr</span>
                    <span class="line">Earragan Mac Ainnir nan lonng,</span>
                    <span class="line">A Righ bu mhaith a làmh 's a lann.</span>
                </span>



                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Chruinnich Righ Lochlann mor shluagh</span>
                    <span class="line">Cabhlach cruaidh a dh'fhàs gu treun:</span>

                    <span class="catchword">Dh'èirich</span>


                    <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 005"></span>

                    <span class="pagenum" id="p5">5</span>

                    <span class="line">Dh'èirich sud o'n àirde tuath</span>
                    <span class="line">Naoi Righrin, 's an sluagh leis.</span>
                </span>


                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Sheol iad air an abhais àrd</span>
                    <span class="line">O chòrs Eirinn bu gharg gàir </span>
                    <span class="line">Gu h Albuinn fhlathail nam Fiann </span>
                    <span class="line">Thogadar an triath th' air muir.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Teachdoireachd thainig∧ thugainn gu luath,</span>
                    <span class="line">Sgeula cruaidh chuir ruinn gu geur,</span>
                    <span class="line">Còmhrag nam fear Innse-fàil </span>
                    <span class="line">Fhaolainn air an tràigh mu dheas.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Thairig Fionn doibh cumha mhòr</span>
                    <span class="line">Làn an tunna do'n dearg òr:</span>
                    <span class="line">Do Righ Lochlann nan arm sean,</span>
                    <span class="line">Araon, agus a bhean fein.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Lochlannaich a bhuithinn bhorb</span>
                    <span class="line">Le meud an stoirm as an lèathachd</span>
                    <span class="line">Cha ghabh iad cumha fui'm ghrein</span>
                    <span class="line">Gun an Fheinn a bhi 'n an dèigh</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Comhairl' eil' a chinn aig Fionn,</span>
                    <span class="line">'S aig maithibh na Feinne gu leir;</span>
                    <span class="line">Nighean Righ na' n gabht' i uath,</span>
                    <span class="line">Gun d'fhuair è sud, 's a bhean fhein.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="catchword">Chuir</span>

                <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 006"></span>

                <span class="pagenum" id="p6">6</span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Chuir sinn 'ga fhios nighean Righ</span>
                    <span class="line">Bu ghuirme sùil, 's bu ghrinne meur;</span>
                    <span class="line">Chuir sinne ga coimhead ceud each</span>
                    <span class="line">A b'fhearr ris an deachaidh srian,</span>
                    <span class="line">Le'n ceud marcaich air a' muin</span>
                    <span class="line">Fui' chulaibh shròil le'n laste gniomh</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Theirinn i'n sud air n raon,</span>
                    <span class="line">'S dh'fhàg i 'na dèigh na h eich,</span>
                    <span class="line">Thug i ceum uighe d' an coir</span>
                    <span class="line">'S da choinnleir air 'na làimh dheis,</span>
                    <span class="line">Da choinneil air ghuaillnibh a guin</span>
                    <span class="line">'S dealbh a chrùin o gheug nam port</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Do naigheachds' o phobull Fhinn</span>
                    <span class="line">Innis dhuinn a bhri', 's a bheachd?</span>
                    <span class="line">Mo naigheachds' o phobull Fhinn</span>
                    <span class="line">Gum faigheadh tu bhri' gu ceart;</span>
                </span>


                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Mu rinn do bhean ort beairt chli,</span>
                    <span class="line">'S gun d'iomair i 'n gniomh gu cearr:</span>
                    <span class="line">Thoir cairdeas is comunn do dh'Fhionn</span>
                    <span class="line">'S gum faigheadh tu mi 'na geall.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Gheibhe tu sud is ciad seud,</span>
                    <span class="line">Is ciad leug o'n uirbhich shaor:</span>
                    <span class="line">Gheibhe tu <del>sud</del>ceud seothag suairc'</span>
                    <span class="line">Air am bitheadh buaidh nan eun:</span>
                </span>
                <span class="catchword">Gheibhe</span>


                <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 007"></span>

                <span class="pagenum" id="p7">7</span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Gheibhe tu sud is ciad mias</span>
                    <span class="line">Do chùrsa Righ bheath' an àidh,</span>
                    <span class="line">'S ge b' è ghleidheadh iad r' a bheo</span>
                    <span class="line">Chumadh iad duin' òg a ghnà.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Gheibhe tu sud is ciad greidh,</span>
                    <span class="line">Is làn Glinne do chridh bàn</span>
                    <span class="line">'S a mhacain mar gabh thu sin </span>
                    <span class="line">Thoir leat do bhean, 's thoir dhuinne sith.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">'Ta cha d'thugainn sith do neach</span>
                    <span class="line">Do dh' Àillidh, no ghin d' ar Feinn,</span>
                    <span class="line">Ach Fionn fein a thigh 'n fui'm bhreith</span>
                    <span class="line">Is a chreach a thoirt gu tràigh.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">'Ta cha d'thug thu leat do neart</span>
                    <span class="line">Na bheireadh a chreach gu tràigh:</span>
                    <span class="line">Falbhai mis' is beannachd leat,</span>
                    <span class="line">O'n chaidh t aithneachd bun os cionn.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Cha'n fahlbh thus' a chiabh na'n cleachd,</span>
                    <span class="line">A Ribhinn fharust a bheoil bhinn</span>
                    <span class="line">Gheibhe tu na seuda saor,</span>
                    <span class="line">'S cheanglainn thu ri m' thaobh deas.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Cha 'n fhan mis' a cheann na'n cliar,</span>
                    <span class="line">O nach traogh mi t fhiamh, is t fhearg;</span>

                    <span class="catchword">'S o</span>


                    <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 008"></span>

                    <span class="pagenum" id="p8">8</span>

                    <span class="line">'S nach faighinn saor fui' m' bhreith</span>
                    <span class="line">Ceann na deise bu | ghann ciall </span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Cha 'n fhàg mi agaibh do theach</span>
                    <span class="line">Do bheinn, no dh' amhuinn, no thulaich;</span>
                    <span class="line">Ach Albuinn a thogail leom</span>
                    <span class="line">'Na cròchcan glas ann am loinngeas.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Thionndaidh i ris a cùl,</span>
                    <span class="line">'S mharcaich i do 'n chùirt gu dian:</span>
                    <span class="line">Bu lion' ar sròl 'ga thogail suas,</span>
                    <span class="line">'S ann òrdugh gu luath chaidh an Fhiann.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Fhreagair Àillidh 'n còmhrag cruaidh, </span>
                    <span class="line">Do 'n t sluagh a thainig ann gèill.</span>
                    <span class="line">Ceann Mhic Nì', Mhic Naomh, Mhic Near,</span>
                    <span class="line">Leigeadh leis air an treas beum.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Deich Ceannarda-fichead d'ar Feinn</span>
                    <span class="line">'S ceann Àillidh fein air an tùs,</span>
                    <span class="line">Thuit sud air laimh Earragainn mhoir</span>
                    <span class="line">Man deachaidh na sloigh ann dlùths'.</span>
                </span>


                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">'N sin chaidh Fionn fein air thùs,</span>
                    <span class="line">Deagh Mhac Chuthaill a ghnuis ghil;</span>
                    <span class="line">'S deich Ceannard-fichead air a laimh dheis,</span>
                    <span class="line">Do shiol Chuthaill na'n cleas lùth.</span>
                </span>
                <span class="catchword">Labhair</span>

                <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 009"></span>

                <span class="pagenum" id="p9">9</span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Labhair Fionn flath na'n cuach,</span>
                    <span class="line">Ri maithibh uaislibh Innse-fàil;</span>
                    <span class="line">Co dh'iongas Earragainn sa ghreis</span>
                    <span class="line">Nan leigeamaid leis ar tàir.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">'S ann bha fhreagradh sud aig Goll</span>
                    <span class="line">An Sonn a bha deachdair achlaoi.</span>
                    <span class="line">D'iongaidh mi Earragainn sa ghreis</span>
                    <span class="line">'S bheir mi d'fheuchainn d'a chleas lùithe.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Mac an Luthaich, 's Diarmad donn,</span>
                    <span class="line">An t Oscar mòr, is Mac an Lèig,</span>
                    <span class="line">Ga d' dhion o shrith-bhuillean an laoich,</span>
                    <span class="line">Cum dithis air gach taobh do d' sgèith.</span>
                </span>


                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Dolphinne Mac Mhalcain o'n Ghrèig</span>
                    <span class="line">* Muime Earragainn, 's cha bi bhreug,</span>
                    <span class="line">'N àm sgathach a chinn d' a dhaltadh</span>
                    <span class="line">A Ri' mhòir bu do amhluidh iomairt:</span>
                    <span class="line">'S mar bhithe mi 's Fionn nam fleadh</span>
                    <span class="line">Gum buineadh è 'n ceann do'n chearthar.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="footnotes">Footnotes: * Ge d' a tha ùghdar na h eachdrui so
                    a'g radh gum b'e Dolphinne Muime
                    Earragainn, tha 'n leughair r 'a thuig=,
                    sinn gur è Oide bha ann. </span>

                <span class="mspage" id="MS Gen 1042_9 010"></span>

                <span class="pagenum" id="p10">10</span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Seachd fichead 's mìle sonn</span>
                    <span class="line">Thuit le Garadh, 's thuit le Goll:</span>
                    <span class="line">Urdal le <del>Oissain an</del> Oscar an àidh,</span>
                    <span class="line">'S le Conall, 's le Coireall cneas bhàn.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">'S air a bhaiste thainig orm</span>
                    <span class="line">A <del>Phadric</del>, chleirich a chanas na sailm,</span>
                    <span class="line">Thuit leam fein, 's le Fionn nam fleadh</span>
                    <span class="line">A cheart choi'-lion ceann ris a chearthar.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">'S mar duine chaidh as am beul airm,</span>
                    <span class="line">No chaidh mar cheo do 'n ghrein;</span>
                    <span class="line">Do dh'arm Righ Lochlann gu fior</span>
                    <span class="line">Cha 'n fhac' iad riamh an tir fein.</span>
                </span>

                <span class="line-group">
                    <span class="line">Tuille mor is leith nam Fiann,</span>
                    <span class="line">Thuit iad air an t sliabh mu dheas;</span>
                    <span class="line">'S ge d' thainig cuid dhinne as </span>
                    <span class="line">Cha d' rinn sinn an lath' ud ar leas.</span>
                </span>



            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Ricky Mo, thank you so much for this, it looks neater and more precise indeed. A meta-question: I can see the code returning expecting results in your snippet. Nevertheless I cannot get it to work on my website. I get currentPage undefined, in the `if (mspage != currentPage)` line. What am I missing? Also, are the theree dots before the querySelectorAll instruction correct?

Comment: Hello again, I now learned about the three dots, which I didn't know. The issue is that my HTML is in a hidden tab (still in the DOM, though) when the page loads and the JavaScript, which waits for the DOM to be loaded anyway, doesn't grab the `mspage` elements. Is there a reason why? I can I grab the elements even if they're hidden from view? Shouldn't it make any difference?

Comment: Are you sure the DOM is already loaded when you call `document.querySelectorAll(".mspage")`?